# Spyder 3.2.8: Code only adopts changes for the first time after that restart of Spyder/Kernel necessary

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, spyder

So originally i thought it only affected changes to my plots but no changes to my code are applied even after saving the *.py file.

After updating to Spyder 3.2.8 the problem still persists.
I found a workaround by restarting the kernel and then rerunning the code so i don't have to close and reopen spyder every time at least.

The problem with this solution is that all my variables are deleted ofc. I found a solution to my problem here
[Spyder IDE reload code with run selection ('F9')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824562/spyder-ide-reload-code-with-run-selection-f9)

and here [IPython 3.2.1 documentation.](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html)

But when i enter the the first command in ipthyon it tells me it's already activated and after that neither %autoreload nor %autoreload 2 seem  to have an effect.
As an example for my problem you can basically take the code example at the IPython 3.2.1 documentation link. For me it wouldn't update from 42 to 43 but still stay at 42.

Another thing is it seems to adopt the first changes i do. I start Spyder run my code everything is fine. I then change something in a *.py file like changing the name of an axis label in a plot. If i run the whole code again or just the changed function with the IPython console it works and integrates the change accordingly. But after that no changes are updated anymore.

Comment: I think you need to spend some more words on clearly explaining the problem. Which steps do you take to arrive a which result? What exactly is undesired about it?

Comment: i edited my questions and tried to make it more clear. The situation is undesired for me because i'm rather new to coding and have to try a lot to get the result i like for my plots. So it's really inconvenient to have to restart Spyder everytime i want to see changes i made to my axis ticks or legend etc.

Comment: I still don't understand the issue. What code do you put where (in the code window, or the console)? What do you do then? (Do press "run" button? Do you press enter?) What code do you then add? What do you do after having added that code? What is the result?

Comment: The latest version of Spyder is 3.2.8

Comment: Have you tried just saving the files after changes have been made?

Comment: You need to understand that with the information available, there is zero hope for help. The key is that you make your case reproducible for others.

Comment: I made a little bit of progress regarding my problem and updated the original question.